# HTTPS Webserver Access

Tags: webserver

I used to use [Expression Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Web) on Windows to gain access to my HTTPS Webserver, for class when I was coding sites. What program will do so on Linux? It's like 145.5.67/MyName23

--Edit-- Expression Web allows me to edit ON the HTTPS webserver without downloading anything additional.

Comment: What do you mean by gain access? [Expressions Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Web) is/was an HTML editor. Do you want to edit your web site, or just browse it?

Comment: Years ago I used to work with `Quanta+` / `kdewebdev`, but I'm not quite sure how usable it is today.

Comment: It isn't just an HTML editor. You can gain access to webservers, WebDav and more. That's how I do my work. But the answer below said Linux has no software that can easily open HTTPS Webservers like Expression Web.

Comment: I want to edit the site which in on the webserver. Expression Web allows me to edit ON the HTTPS webserver without downloading anything additional.

Answer (score 3):

Linux has no good integrated software.  You'll need to use 2 pieces of software.

1. A text editor with at least syntax highlighting
2. An FTP Client

In the FTP client provide your username and password, and download the files.  Open them using the text editor.  Work.  Save them, and then re-upload them, making sure to choose replace.

Answer (score 2):

As eyoung says, You need FTP Client and A text Editor.

You can use [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) and set it's editor on your prefered Editor, like Komodo, Kate, Gedit or etc through this URI:

Edit menu -> Settings -> File editing

Then when you connect to your ftp server you can just right click on file and choose edit. After you change the file and click save in your editor, Go to FileZille, FileZilla automatically detects the change and asks you if you want to replace the file to the server.

Also, some ftp clients like [Konqueror](https://konqueror.org/) witch is a global browser, will upload the file without question and shows the ftp directory like a local directory.

Comment: Thanks for this. But for example, if the server I usually access is like this: http://146.111.120.96/FA14/ET_710_C2/myname41/ how will I open this? Is that FTP? I don't think so, right? What are options next?

Comment: In your example 146.111.120.96 is the IP of your server. The server will open your files and process them and show you the result, when you open your site by browser. Usually it will look at "public_html" for regular site and "private_html" for ssl site. when you connect to your server via FTP client, server will show you the root folder of your website. I think You need more information about websites. Go to [site-helper](http://www.site-helper.com/) and read the starting articles or more. These are the basic important information that you need to become a webmaster.

Comment: Thanks for your response and the resources. I think I'm still lacking the answer I need to resolve this, though. For example, can you explain how to connect to the server? For example, with the server example I gave. What do I need on Linux to open the server? What do I type in and where? In Linux. It seems much less complicated on Windows but I've been a Linux user for quite some time now, but not for this type of use.